# How these two Turing machine problems are different in terms of their decidability?

Tags: turing-machines, context-free, automata

I was referring to [slide 4 of this](https://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~deepakd/atc-2011/tm-cfl-undecidable.pdf), which states following:

> It is decidable whether a given CFG accepts a non-empty language?

Then I was reading Intro to Automata theory book by Ullman et al. It states following:

> Let $L_{ne}$ be the language of all codes for Turing machines that accept atleast one input string. 
>   $$L_{ne}=\{M | L(M)\neq \phi\}$$
>   $L_{ne}$ is not recursive.

Knowing that "not recursive" is same as "undecidable" and the functionality of Turing machine is expressed as a CFG, I feel that the problems in above two statements sound same and the statements contradicts each other in terms of their decidability claims. Thus, one of them must be wrong. However I also feel that I still miss something basic and both of them are non contradictory and equally true. But then what I miss?

Answer (score 3):

The thing you missed is that Turing Machines are strictly more expressive than Context-Free Grammars. CFGs are as expressive as push-down automata (PDA, i.e. automata with one stack).

E.g. the language $L = \{a^nb^nc^n | n > 0\}$ cannot be expressed by CFG (or decided by a PDA), but can be decided by a Turing Machine.

So, for CFG, the emptiness problem is decidable, but somewhere on the way to Turing completeness, this property is lost.

Comment: Ahhhh I mistook CFG for unrestricted grammar...The functionality of TM can be expressed with the help of unrestricted grammar (of form $(V\cup T)^+\rightarrow(V\cup T)^*$), whereas PDA functinality is expressed as CFG (taking form $V\rightarrow(V\cup T)^*$). So I think I can say that "its decidable whether language accepted by a PDA is empty or not". Right?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit subtle. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Undecidable_problems) says the following:

> A CFG can be constructed that generates all strings that are not accepting computation histories for a particular Turing machine on a particular input

That means you can reduce the halting problem to the problem, *"Does this CFG generate all strings?"*, but not necessarily to the problem *"Does this CFG generate the empty language?"*.